# Best way to update TextView, every minute, on the minute

Tags: android, user-interface, clock

My problem is similar to this one, [How to update a widget every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872267/how-to-update-widget-every-minute), however I only want to update TextView of the UI.  I need access to the time so unfortunately can not simply use the DigitalClock view.

Ive been researching and have found ways to update every minute, but not on the minute so they are synchronised with the system clock (so they might be up to 59 seconds out of sync!)

The only ways I can think to do it are 
(a) Run a handler (or timer) every second (which seems a bit like overkill if I only want to update every minute) [Like this from the android.com resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

(b) Have a service running in background.  (I'm not keen on this as I already have more important things running in the background)

(c) use Alarm Manager (again seems like overkill)

Seems to be such an easy thing to do, and yet...

Any advice appreciated
Mel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try configuring a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to run a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) that updates your TextView every minute (see its [schedule](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) method).

Comment: Thankyou, this idea worked. I got the current date, subtracted seconds and milliscounds so it was a rounded minute. Then I added one full minute as when to begin. Finally, I set it the timer to renew every minute (60 000 milliseconds)

Comment: Here is some code if anyone is interested. The code written by Steve Ody (http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12) was very helpful. 'code' myTimer = new Timer(); GregorianCalendar calCreationDate = new GregorianCalendar(); int intMilli = calCreationDate.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND); int intSeconds = calCreationDate.get(Calendar.SECOND); calCreationDate.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (-1*intMilli)); calCreationDate.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1*intSeconds); calCreationDate.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1); Date dateStartDate = calCreationDate.getTime(); 'code'

Comment: Timers in Android work, but they are NOT the preferred way. Use Handlers instead of Timers!

Answer (score 43):

The accepted answer does not respond specifically to the question. The OP asks for a way to receive some sort of event **on time** (at the system clock minute and 00 seconds).

Using a Timer is not the right way to do this. It's not only overkill, but you must resort to some tricks to make it right.

The right way to do this (ie. update a TextView showing the time as HH:mm) is to use BroadcastReceiver like this :

```
BroadcastReceiver _broadcastReceiver;
private final SimpleDateFormat _sdfWatchTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
private TextView _tvTime;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    _broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)
                    _tvTime.setText(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));
            }
        };

    registerReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (_broadcastReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
}
```

The system will send this broadcast event at the exact beginning of every minutes based on system clock. Don't forget however to initialize your TextView beforehand (to current system time) since it is likely you will pop your UI in the middle of a minute and the TextView won't be updated until the next minute happens.

Comment: your code is working great! Thanks..How to update time per second?

Comment: Unfortunately ACTION_TIME_TICK is fixed on the minute. If I ever needed a TextView to show current time with seconds, I think I would use a separate TextView for the seconds and handle it with a simple Timer (resynched every minute by the BroadCastReceiver to avoid any long run bias). The point to not use a Timer is that basically, you want to see the minute changes ON THE MINUTE of the real time. Seconds are generally not a problem if slightly off, but resynching every minute should do the trick forever.

Comment: Guys its working perfectly, First I have set the date in onCreate, and then on every minute it get updated from the broadcastReciever.

Comment: where should I register the reciever? in `AppWidgetProvider` ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

Comment: Thankyou for your replay.  Even though the article on android.com recommended handlers, Steve Ody's article put me off a bit!

Answer (score -1):

This is what I used :

```
int secsUntilOnTheMinute=60-Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND);

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateSendTimesHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}, secsUntilOnTheMinute*1000, 60000);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation instead of just posting code.

Comment: You shouldn't use TimerTask as it is not reliable. See more on: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks