# How to synchronize the time interval with button event in android?

Tags: android, methods, time, intervals, synchronize

I want my app to check running tasks after every 10 secs of some specific button event.

I used `Timer` to do this work for me but `Timer` is synchronized with system clock not with my button event and i want this time interval to be synchronized with my button event. for ex its been 3 seconds since my app is started and i am clicking on my button after 3 seconds so all tasks should be loaded after 10 secs of these total(3+3) 6 seconds but its loading the tasks after(10-3-3) 4 seconds.

Is there any way to synchronize this time interval with my button event?

Sorry if i am unable to make you understand my question. If anyone understand what i just said please feel free to edit my question so everyone can understand it easily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem in that I wanted the timer to fire every minute, (though I wanted to sync with the clock).  Nonetheless, like in my problem, I think the schedule method of the Timer class might help you.

Here is the link to that post.

[Best way to update TextView, every minute, on the minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457186/best-way-to-update-textview-every-minute-on-the-minute)

Hope it helps, 
Mel