# Checking an already filtered Intent for its action

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to run a task on every minute, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457186/best-way-to-update-textview-every-minute-on-the-minute) Problem is already analogue to mine. A user posted the following:

```java
BroadcastReceiver _broadcastReceiver;
private final SimpleDateFormat _sdfWatchTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
private TextView _tvTime;

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    _broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
            {
                if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)
                    _tvTime.setText(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));
            }
        };

    registerReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    if (_broadcastReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
}
```

My problem is to understand the if statement inside `onReceive`.

1. Why does it have to be 0? What does it say?
2. Why is it necessary to check for the action ACTION_TIME_TICK in the first place, when we already set an IntentFilter with that action?

I would have asked this question in the original context, but I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: **1)** It's equivalent to `Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK.equals(intent.getAction())`. You check whether the received intent really has the expected action. **2)** Normally BroadcastReceivers can listen to multiple actions. ... Maybe others will provide more reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it have to be 0? What does it say?

Well, let's break it apart.

```
intent.getAction()
```

If you look [right here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getAction()), basically it tells you what the intent is doing. It returns a String. `Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK` is actually a String.

```
.compareTo() == 0
```

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) compares two objects (in this case, strings). When you check if it equals 0, you are checking if the two strings are equal, the same.

So putting it together,

```
intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0
```

This checks whether the the action for the intent is the Broadcast action `ACTION_TIME_TICK`.

---

> Why is it necessary to check for the action ACTION_TIME_TICK in the first place, when we already set an IntentFilter with that action?

Sometimes you accidentally (or purposely register) the same BroadcastReceiver several times, with different intent filters. Your BroadcastReceiver would be receiving broadcasts for several different actions. In the `onReceive` method, you would want to make sure you are responding to the appropriate action.