# Correct way to update listView every 30 seconds according to system time

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm currently trying to implement a time-based two-factor authentication in an Android App. The code needs to be updated every 30 seconds, according to the system time on the phone, eg. 21:13:00 and 21:13:30 (H:M:S). I was looking into the BroadcastReceiver with Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK, but this is only on every minute. My idea was to use this and then a timer inside the method that is called from the BroadcastReceiver. However i'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it or if there is another way i can get like a BroadcastReceiver on every 30'th second. Keep in mind that it is important that it follows the system time, or else the codes might expire on the server end.

Currently my code follows, this earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457186/best-way-to-update-textview-every-minute-on-the-minute/13059819#13059819)

```
BroadcastReceiver _broadcastReceiver;
private final SimpleDateFormat _sdfWatchTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
private TextView _tvTime;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    _broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)
                    _tvTime.setText(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));
                    //Extra timer here, for the 30 second update..
            }
        };

    registerReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (_broadcastReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a broadcast receiver isn't the ideal solution, this solution will be much more accurate and it MUCH easier to write/maintain than B.Reciever and intents.

The better way is to post a delayed runnable to the UI thread's Looper through a handler

```
static final private int DELAY_TIME = 30*1000;

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      /* do what you need to do */
      YOUR CODE HERE
      /* post new handler to re-trigger in 30 seconds */
      // wrap this in IF statement to make a way of stopping the looping.
      handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY_TIME );
   }
};

// create a handler that points to the UI Thread's Looper
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
// post the first runnable, that will start a cascading repeat set of runnables
handler.postDelayed(runnable, DELAY_TIME );
```

Comment: Glad to help, I've literally proctored Univ. lectures teaching this material and helped  with the course content. So I know a few other areas you should be careful of. Impl. a Handler like this is safe, but as soon as you start having custom `handleMessage(Message msg)` you will face memory leak issues if you don't do a couple things 1) Make the inner class static 2) use a WeakReference<Activity> to store the reference to the outer activity. 3) always use that weakRef.get() to 'access' the Activity. 4) never store #3's return value within the custom Handler

Comment: The above comment is really meant more for when you want to do more complicated background processing. But that info is a big 'gotcha' in Android when using the HaMeR (Ha-ndler, Me-ssagers, and R-unnables framework (My PhD Adviser coined that term) ) That hasn't always been discussed widely(or properly). (It took me quite a while to figure out how to handle it appropriately)

Comment: I'll leave out the finer details as to 'why' you need to do this, but 'basically' you can have a long running background thread that 'should' go away, but it has a circular set of refs with the Activity, this circular set of refs. (pointers) will prevent the Activity from being Garbage Collected when it can be. This is a slightly different 'memory leak' than most people think of, but it still eats up memory of the system that should be available otherwise. If your thread doesn't halt, then it could even be indefinitely (until app is removed from memory/force stopped/phone rebooted/etc)