# Updating a clock in main activity

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

Im trying to get into Android Development and want to create a simple app, that shows the current time in a TextView and updates every minute.
I managed to get the time initialized, but can't figure out how to update it.

I googled a lot and am now trying to create a broadcast receiver that updates the TextView.
That's what I got so far:

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarmcompanion">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".TimeBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.alarmcompanion

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        clock.text = getString(R.string.time, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE))

    }
}
class TimeBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive( context: Context, intent: Intent){
        clock.text = getString(R.string.time, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE))
    }
}
```

The debugger says, that `clock` and `getString` are unresolved references, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix that.
For `clock` I get this error:

```
    Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
    public val Activity.clock: TextView! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
    public val Dialog.clock: TextView! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
    public val android.app.Fragment.clock: TextView! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
    public val androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.clock: TextView! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/time"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="120sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.
Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anybody stumble across this post, I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059819/9552448

The code seems to belong into the MainActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

```
R.string.time
```

Is a link on your strings xml resource file tag which probably doesn't contain this string. getString(id: Int) is a function in Context. In receiver you should invoke it like that context.getString(id). Your receiver knows nothing about TextView, it is variable of Activity only. You can share the link on it as global variable. But it's a bad practice and can lead memory leak! Another way is to make your receiver inner class of activity

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The string is in the xml resource file and works for the initial setting of the clock in the main activity. I believe if that would be the problem, the clock wouldn't even set on start up.

Comment: try also add R class import. I don't see it in your code. Sth like  - import com.example.alarmcompanion.R

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work either. I don't think the problem is with the `R.string.time` part. For some reason it doesn't know the TextView `clock` or the function `getString`. I'm guessing I have to import the view somehow, but I don't know how...

Comment: It important without R class you can't get sting by it's id. I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the `getString` part. Do you have an idea for making the `clock` view known?
I added the error I get to my question

Comment: Without layout.activity_main.xml file it is difficult

Comment: I added the xml and the error, thanks for your help

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm at the beginning of learning Android development. Could you please explain how I would make the receiver an inner class of the activity?

Comment: So I just copied and pasted the receiver class inside the main activity, below the onCreate function, but it still doesn't know `clock`