# Android widget not updating when it's not shown

Tags: android, widget, updating

I have a widget that counts down time. 
It's on the main Home screen and it seems to work fine while i'm staying on the Home screen, 
BUT when i switch to another screen for a while and then get back to HOME, widget starts lagging.

It seems like it doesn't do updates while I was on other screen, cause the time isn't updated and now it's performing all updates all together calculating the countdown time. This causes lags, and short phone freezes (this when i call update each minute). In case I want to update each second - phone freezes totally after about 20 minutes of screen lock time or other out of focus action.

Question: can I implicitly tell widget to continue the updates regardless if it's shown on screen, or not? Or how else can this issue be solved?

Comment: How are you getting keeping the time when the view is not in focus.

Comment: Well actually that doesn't concern me as much as the fact that after it gets in focus it is seems to call all the updates it missed and not only one (last)

Comment: I only asked because I was thinking that you could take the system time at the point the widget goes out of focus and then take it again when it comes back into focus, do a little math and get your time like that....its just an idea and Im not sure about the details and how your code looks like but it might save on having to use incremental updates in the background all the time.

Comment: can I catch onFocus in a sense of when the widget is not on the screen? cause what i've seen in forums was onFocus-  when someone clicks on the widget.

Answer (score 0):

View.OnFocusChangeListener

Im guessing you can use this to monitor whether or not your widget is in focus or not. Check it out on the google docs. I have yet to use it myself so Im not sure it would work but its definitely worth a try.

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad overall design - if you must count each "tick" and have it happen at that time, a service is probably the best thing to do the work, and just have the widget ask the service what it should display.

But... you're going to suck battery something awful.  Does it really need to do something on each tick, or can you just store the last draw time, find the current time and then update accordingly, skipping all the ticks inbetween?

And if something needs to happen when it hits zero, try using the android Alarm system.  You'll be so much nicer to your user's battery life and CPU doing it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your are doing that or not, but you have to use the AlarmManager class to update you widget. Don't use any threads or something that may cause the delay.
I used it and it worked for me. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872267/how-to-update-widget-every-minute)