# Develop a widget for a existing android apps

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to develop a widget for a existing android apps.

The only function i want is to display the variable i get from the apps.
I have developed a simple function to get variable from it but i don't know how to update it when the apps is closed.

Or i have to write a service to get these variable?

```
package hkcsl.tabbedactivealarm;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class AppWidgetExample extends AppWidgetProvider {   
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  super.onReceive(context, intent);     
  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.helloworld);
  String value1 = intent.getStringExtra("Value"); 
  views.setTextViewText(R.id.text, value1);
  AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, AppWidgetExample.class), views);
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand the question -

Yes, it's possible, but i believe that the update interval must be less frequent than once per minute. refer to this guide for a simple tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html#simplewidget

Yeah, your app needs a process that runs while your app is closed. so a background service or an AsyncTask or Thread would do. Background Service is your best choice

**edit**

okay i think i undersatnd better now. using that same link above, read section 4.

```
`appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);`
```

you only start 1 service, and the service takes care of updating values. if you want something special to happen upon the user exiting your app, you can override `onDestroy()`?

**edit 2**

use something like this in the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/YOUR_LAYOUT"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="300000" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

notice the `updatePeriodMillis=300000`

this was taken from section 3 of that article link above

Comment: Do u mean i have to write another service to do so?
or just broadcast the intent from the activity and it will keep running

Comment: @DannyHo wait, now i'm confused. are you getting the variables from another developer's app?

Comment: oh. then it shouldn't be that bad. umm... let me edit my answer

Comment: @DannyHo basically, yes, have another service that extends `Service` class, and that class will be doing the updating. by the way, is AppWidgetProvider a service in of itself? i had no idea

Comment: These information are very useful for me. I can now update the widget by the service once. But i still not understand that how to trigger "updateAppWidget" update widget periodically?

Comment: @DannyHo Ah. gotcha, sorry, i forgot to mention this line: `updatePeriodMillis` in your android XML file. see my edited answer. it's in section 3. of that link i gave you. By the way, on StackOVerflow, in the future, you should upvote an answer if it's good, but you should only accept answers once they fully answer ALL of your questions :) because otherwise i might have missed your comment. (upvoting is done by hitting the up arrow above the ratings number, though im not sure how much reputation you need to do so)

Comment: I sincere thanks a lot for your answers. But maybe i asked not clearly, i would like to update it periodically about 5 mins, but there is a minimum 30 min for "updatePeriodMillis"

Comment: Shoot. I'm sorry, i didn't read that part. maybe take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872267/how-to-update-widget-every-minute